# How does Django Channels Group/channel_session work?

Tags: django-channels

It seems Group and channel_session can persist across multiple message sessions and consumers. How does Channels achieve that?

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    # Add them to the right group
    message.channel_session['room'] = 'room name'
    Group("chat-%s" % message.user.username[0]).add(message.reply_channel)

@channel_session_user
def ws_disconnect(message):
    if 'room' in message.channel_session:
        print('room====', message.channel_session['room'])
    Group("chat-%s" % message.user.username[0]).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

I would like to setup a long existing object, much like a global object which is accessible by every consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@channel_session` (or the `@channel_session_user`) decorator to achieve this.  Make sure your object is serializable, then just add it to the user's channel session like this:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    message.session.myobject = {'test': True}

@channel_session_user
def ws_connect(message):
    print(message.session.myobject)   # should output {'test': True}
```

Alternatively, just use your DB or redis to persist things like you would normally in Django:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    redis_conn.set('my-persisted-key', "{'test': True}")

@channel_session_user
def ws_connect(message):
    print(redis_conn.get('my-persisted-key'))  # should output "{'test': True}"
```

Comment: I know it's ben long, but how can I access `message.session.myobject = {'test': True}` from a regular view?

Comment: You cant @zerohedge, they are separate session objects.  You will need to store the session_key somewhere manually and get the session from `SessionStore`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views

Comment: Thanks for trying to assist (I'm still trying to solve this). When you say "store somewhere", can I store it somewhere that's ephemeral, but that *will* be available for the duration of the connection? So can I set a session key in the `consumer` and retrieve from the `view`?

Comment: my question for a better generalized question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51187309/5013234 thanks!

Comment: They are separate sessions entirely, you will not be able to set things from the ws session and have them appear in the http session.  To access the http session you'll need to store its session_id in the database somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. With Channels 2, would it be possible? http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/sessions.html

Comment: It is possible in Channels 2, calling `scope["session"].save()` inside the websocket handler will save any modifications back to the HTTP session, which is accessible from the view.

Comment: And am I correct to assume that that will save me the persistent storage of sessions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174451/discussion-between-nick-sweeting-and-zerohedge).

Comment: I’ve gone ahead and upgraded to Channels 2 specifically for this, but I’m experiencing the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236316/django-channels-2-not-persisting-session-data-set-in-connect