# django-channels: differentiate between different `AnonymousUser`s

Tags: django, django-channels

Unfortunately I'm using django-channels channels 1.1.8, as I missed all the 
updates to channels 2.0. Upgrading now is unrealistic as we've just 
launched and this will take some time to figure out correctly.

Here's my problem:

I'm using the *message.user.id *to differentiate between authenticated 
users that I need to send messages to. However, there are cases where I'll 
need to send messages to un-authenticated users as well - and that message 
depends on an external API call. I have done this in *ws_connect()*:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    # create group for user
    if str(message.user) == "AnonymousUser":
        user_group = "AnonymousUser" + str(uuid.uuid4())
    else:
        user_group = str(message.user.id)


    print(f"user group is {user_group}")
    Group(user_group).add(message.reply_channel)
    Group(user_group).send({"accept": True})
    message.channel_session['get_user'] = user_group
```

This is only the first part of the issue, basically I'm appending a random 
string to each AnonymousUser instance. But I can't find a way to access 
this string from the request object in a view, in order to determine *who* 
I am sending the message *to*.

Is this even achievable? Right now I'm not able to access anything set in 
the *ws_connect* in my view.

EDIT: Following kagronick's advice, I tried this:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    # create group for user

    if str(message.user) == "AnonymousUser":
        user_group = "AnonymousUser" + str(uuid.uuid4())
    else:
        user_group = str(message.user.id)

    Group(user_group).add(message.reply_channel)
    Group(user_group).send({"accept": True})
    message.channel_session['get_user'] = user_group
    message.http_session['get_user'] = user_group
    print(message.http_session['get_user'])
    message.http_session.save()
```

However, `http_session` is `None` when user is `AnonymousUser`. Other decorators didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save to the session and access it in the view. But you need to use the http_session and not the channel session. Use the `@http_session` decorator or `@channel_and_http_session`. You may need to call message.http_session.save() (I don't remember, I'm on Channels 2 now.). But after that you will be able to see the user's group in the view.

Also, using a group for this is kind of overkill. If the group will only ever have 1 user, put the reply_channel in the session and do something like `Channel(request.session['reply_channel']).send()` in the view. That way it doesn't need to look up the one user that is in the group and can send directly to the user.

If this solves your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I *am* using  http session on the consumer, but still couldn’t m access the session key in the view.

Comment: Try calling .save() on it.

Comment: Your code above is using the channel session. Can you update your code with what you have now?

Comment: `message.http_session` does work when the user is logged in, but not when's not (returns `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`). Which is weird. The decorator I'm using for ws_connect() is `@channel_session_user_from_http`

Comment: The problem seems to be, with all decorators, is that when the user isn't logged, the `message.http_session` is `None`.

Comment: Try this decerator from auth @channel_and_http_session_user_from_http

Comment: I did. It's still `None`. Django I guess creates sessions only for logged-in users.

Comment: Django session docs says "Django provides full support for anonymous sessions. "

Comment: I know. I've gone over that, and I have sessions enabled. But `message.http_session` is none if the user isn't authenticated...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: unfortunately this only works locally but not in production. when AnonymousUser, `message.http_sesssion` doesn't exist.

user `kagronick` got me on the right track, where he pointed that `message` has an  `http_session` attribute. However,  it seems `http_session` is always `None` in `ws_connect` when user is AnonymousUser, which defeats our purpose.

I've solved it by checking if the user is Anonymous **in the view**, and if he is, which means he doesn't have a session (or at least channels can't see it), initialize one, and assign the key `get_user` the value  `"AnonymousUser" + str(uuid.uuid4())` (this way previously done in the consumer).

After I did this, every time `ws_connect` is called `message` will have an `http_session` attribute: Either the user ID when one is logged in, or `AnonymousUser-uuid.uuid4()`.