# Django-Channels 2 not persisting session data set in `connect`

Tags: python, django, django-channels

`channels==2.1.2` | `channels-redis==2.2.1` | `daphne==2.2.0` | `Django==1.11.6`

I've upgraded to Channels 2 specifically for the ability to **access and modify** the session from within a consumer (and access it in a view), but that doesn't seem to be working. Basically, I want to identify `AnonymousUser`s and send them messages (each his own, not all of them together).

Here's my `routing.py` file:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            core.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Here's my `consumers.py` file:

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        if self.scope['user'].is_authenticated:
            user_id = str(self.scope['user'].id)
            self.scope['session']['user_identifier']= user_id
            self.group_name = user_id
        else:
            user_id = str(self.scope['user']) + str(uuid.uuid4())
            self.scope['session']['user_identifier'] = user_id
            self.group_name = user_id

        self.scope['session'].save()

        print(f" in consumer: {self.scope['session']['user_identifier']}")

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()
```

And in the view where I need to use `send`, I'm trying to get the group_name (`user_identifier`) from the session in case of an AnonymousUser:

```
def get_spotify_link(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_identifier = str(request.user.id)
    else:
        user_identifier = request.session['user_identifier']
        print(f"in get_spotify_link: {user_identifier}")
```

However, I'm intermittently (well, 99% of time) getting `KeyError: 'user_identifier'`.

```
Internal Server Error: /get_spotify_link/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/PycharmProjects/artist_notify/core/views.py", line 442, in get_spotify_link
    user_identifier = request.session['user_identifier']
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 57, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
KeyError: 'user_identifier'
[2018/07/08 20:54:03] WebSocket HANDSHAKING / [127.0.0.1:65478]
 in consumer: AnonymousUser8883761c-f673-413e-82e2-413d1cbb17e3
[2018/07/08 20:54:03] WebSocket CONNECT / [127.0.0.1:65478]
Internal Server Error: /get_spotify_link/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/PycharmProjects/artist_notify/core/views.py", line 442, in get_spotify_link
    user_identifier = request.session['user_identifier']
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 57, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
KeyError: 'user_identifier'
```

Comment: Seems like a race condition, are you sure that `connect()` is completely finished running before `get_spotify_link` is called?

Comment: @NickSweeting yes. 100%. I’ve also done tests with simply refreshing the same page after connect is called, with prints before and after setting the session variable, and it wasn’t saved. On Channels’ GitHub was told that this is due to the way “my code interacts” with Channels, but it doesn’t do anything special..